# How to set default value in dropdownlistfor using ViewBag

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have seen other questions of same Title being asked before. I've tried them, but they are not working.

I have a main list which I'm fetching like this:

```
ViewBag.ProgramListChecker = manager.GetProgramListForCommittee(RegistrationId);
```

`GetProgramListForCommittee` method is populating as:

```
public List<ProgramListCheckerEntity> GetProgramListForCommittee(int RegistrationId)
    {
        try
        {
            List<ProgramListCheckerEntity> list = new List<ProgramListCheckerEntity>();
            DataTable dt = _repository.GetProgramListForCommittee(RegistrationId);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    ProgramListCheckerEntity obj = new ProgramListCheckerEntity();
                    obj.ItemName = dr.IsNull("ItemName") ? "" : dr["ItemName"].ToString();
                    obj.ResultOption = dr.IsNull("SelectedOptionName") ? "" : dr["SelectedOptionName"].ToString();
                    obj.Remarks = dr.IsNull("Remarks") ? "" : dr["Remarks"].ToString();
                    obj.CheckListRowId = dr.IsNull("CheckListRowId") ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(dr["CheckListRowId"]);
                    obj.CommitteeActionId = dr.IsNull("CommitteeActionId") ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(dr["CommitteeActionId"]);
                    obj.CommitteeRemarks = dr.IsNull("CommitteeRemarks") ? "" : dr["CommitteeRemarks"].ToString();
                    list.Add(obj);
                }
            }

            return list;
        }
```

And another list I'm using for dropdown values:

```
 ViewBag.InspectionActionList = obj.GetMasterTableList("Master.InspectionAction", "ActionId", "ActionName", "");
```

Method for this is :-

```
public List<DropDownEntity> GetMasterTableList(string TableName, string DataValueField, string DataTextField)
    {
        var parms = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        var spName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GetMasterTableList"];

        parms.Add("@TableName", TableName);
        parms.Add("@DataValueField", DataValueField);
        parms.Add("@DataTextField", DataTextField);

        return DataTableToList(_dbAccess.GetDataTable(spName, parms));
    }
```

I want to have default value in the dropdown from `ViewBag.ProgramListChecker` with list populated from `ViewBag.InspectionActionList` . Although the list is populating but default value is not selecting.

This is my cshtml:

```
<table id="tblList" class="table dva-table dva-tborder agencygrid">
    <tbody>
        @{int counter = 0; }

        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ProgramListChecker)
        {
            <tr>
                <td style="width:5%;text-align:center">
                    @(++counter)
                </td>
                <td style="width:25%;text-align:left">
                    @item.ItemName
                </td>
                <td style="width:10%;text-align:center">
                    @item.ResultOption
                </td>
                <td style="width:25%;text-align:center">
                    @item.Remarks                                    
                </td>
                <td style="width:15%;text-align:center">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CommitteeActionId, new SelectList(ViewBag.InspectionActionList, "DataValueField", "DataTextField", item.CommitteeActionId), new
               {
                   @id = "ddlAction",
                   @class = "form-control requiredValidation"
               })
                </td>
                <td style="width:35%;text-align:center">
                    <input type="text" id="CommitteeRemarks" value="@item.CommitteeRemarks" maxlength="1000" rows="10" class="form-control" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="CheckListRowId" value="@item.CheckListRowId" class="form-control" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is `item.CommitteeActionId` and the `"DataValueField"` in `ViewBag.InspectionActionList` is same type?

Comment: Also share `obj.GetMasterTableList` method code please! There is nothing wrong found in your shared code.

Comment: @TanvirArjel No are not of same type. 'item.CommitteeActionId' is int while DataValueField is string. But they are not in same list.  Modified code for Method

Comment: Yes! That is the problem. These two has to be the same type.

Comment: Oh really?? Will check that.

Comment: Nopes . I changed both to string . It still didn't get corrected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189767/discussion-between-deepak-and-tanvirarjel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First ensure that `item.CommitteeActionId` and the `"DataValueField"` in `ViewBag.InspectionActionList` are the same type and then use different name for the `DropDownList` as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ComActionId", new SelectList(ViewBag.InspectionActionList, "DataValueField", "DataTextField", item.CommitteeActionId), new
               {
                   @id = "ddlAction",
                   @class = "form-control requiredValidation"
               })
```

Here I have used `ComActionId` for example. Now it should work.